# Why is %2 used rather than &1 to determine parity

Tags: python

I have noticed that the most common way to determine whether a number is even in python is `x%2`. Wouldn't `x&1` be faster? What disadvantages does it have?

Comment: There are only 10 types of people in the world: those who understand binary, and those who don't.

Comment: They're probably identical in performance.

Comment: That's not "parity". that's just an even/odd test. parity checks if there's an even/odd number of true or false bits in a particular value.

Comment: @MarcB In mathematics, "parity" means being even or odd.

Comment: This isn't mathematics, though. This is programming. programming-wise, parity refers to the number of bits in a number, and whether that number is even odd.

Comment: `%` is more general. If you're thinking in terms of divisibility instead of bitwise representations, you'll probably think of `%` before `&`.

Answer (score 3):

`x&1` is very slightly faster at least on my machine, but it's also less immediately readable for most programmers. Bitwise and would tend to suggest to me that you're working on bit strings, while modulo suggests numeric operations, and so unless you're writing a library function that needs to be as fast as possible, I'd tend to opt for the `x%2` formulation.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: l = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)

In [3]: %timeit [x%2 for x in l]
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.3 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit [x&1 for x in l]
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.5 µs per loop

In [5]: [x&1 for x in l] == [x%2 for x in l]
Out[5]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

`%2` is checking the modulus of the number when divided by 2, in otherwords it's checking if the reminder is 1 or 0, while `&1` is the bitwise operator checking if the last bit is the same. The bitwise operator **IS** slightly faster, but the difference is negligible.

IMO the reason I think `%2` is used more is because that makes more sense to the average python programmer that hasn't completely studied bits and operators yet, so to explain `%2` vs `&1`, the `%2` is more user friendly.