# Which is faster a%2 or a&1?

Tags: c++, c

I know the principle of `a&1`:
for example:

```
4&1: 0100
     0001
   = 0000
```

---

and

```
5&1: 0101
     0001
   = 0001
```

But I want to know what and how is the principle of `a%2`

Which is faster, `a%2` or `a&1` ?

Comment: This is implementation and setting dependent. Pick a compiler you care about, compile, and look at the machine code.

Comment: Shouldn't matter to any modern compiler. Whichever is better should be selected by the compiler and used no matter what you specify.

Comment: ok, now I'm lost. You wanna know the modulo operator? or you want to know which language is faster doing those operations? which? or...

Comment: You'll often find the result to be exactly equal. Test it here: https://quick-bench.com/

Comment: Any compiler will choose the best way of doing it - even with no optimizations. Do now worry. https://godbolt.org/z/vPKzPj

Comment: @TedLyngmo always

Comment: i wanna know who is faster a%2 or a&1 i am not talking about any language

Comment: no simple answer - depends on the signes of the first operand.

Comment: @P__J__ I Said "_often_" to not step on any compiler implementors toes :-) There's no _rule_ that says that they must result in the same assembler code.

Comment: Although (a%2) will require a right-shift operation and a subtraction, modern processors perform instructions in parallel - it could still be faster than a single AND instruction. However unlikely, benchmarking is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: duplicates: [What is the fastest way to find if a number is even or odd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2229107/995714), [which is faster to find the even number if(n%2==0) or if(n&1==0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51597019/995714), [Are bitwise operators faster?, if yes then why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63096291/995714), [Why is %2 used rather than &1 to determine parity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38906212/995714)

Comment: @phuclv Not a duplicate: This is c/c++, that is python

Comment: @pppery I used the wrong link. I've already posted the C duplicates above: [What is the fastest way to find if a number is even or odd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2229107/995714)

Comment: It depends on the compiler and, more importantly, on relative speed of different instructions on your target machine.    Assuming `a` is an unsigned type, the result of `a %2` and `a&1` are identical, modern compilers (with sufficient code optimisation enabled) will detect that, and emit the same code for both.    If `a` is a `signed` type, the result of the two expressions differ, so comparing their speed is pointless.

Comment: @user4581301 With modern you mean a compiler that is from the last 30 years or had significant improvements in the last 30 years? This is something almost every compiler can do.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Thirty years sounds about right. I'd expect it to just happen debug build or no, but remember we still field a lot of questions on Turbo C++. But I promise nothing. I've had to use some pretty lame C compilers over the years.

Answer (score 5):

There are two cases:

1. Unsigned integer. Any modern compiler will compile `x % 2` as `x & 1` even without the optimizations. So the speed will be the same as both will have the same machine code.
2. Signed integer - the result of `x % 2` and result of `x & 1` are completely different and in this case you should use `x % 2` to get modulo and `x & 1` to test the LSB. https://godbolt.org/z/cEY4dM

Comment: In the signed case, you should use `x&1` to get actual algebraic modulo or `x%2` to get the bogus C definition of modulo. :-)

Comment: It's not bogus, modulo is a signed operation. `-5 % 2 == -1`.

Comment: @rusty This is getting OT, but certain operations depends on `x/3 - 1 == (x - 3) / 3` for all `x`. This is not the case with c-integer division which rounds toward zero rather than negative infinity. If integer division was rounding towards negative infinity, then  `-5 / 3 == -2` and the corresponding modulo operator would yeld `-5 % 3 == 1`

Comment: @rustyx The `%` is a reminder operation, which is not necessary the same as modulo.